# switching JTextFields by pressing Enter key

Tags: java, swing, focus, jtextfield

I have created number of text fields and I'm wonder how can I switch the focus between the fields by pressing the enter key.

In addition, Can I control the Target field ? for example can I defined that by pressing `Enter` in `field A` the focus will be change to `field C` ?

[image]

Comment: You just need to implement an action listener to `JTextField`, so after you press enter the action is done.

Comment: I know that `ActionListener` Is the key, but how can I control the focus switches ?

Comment: jTextField.requestFocus()

Comment: @GilPeretz You can use `.requestFocus();` on the `JTextField` that you want to be focused.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple example:

Suppose you have two `JTextField`s: `textField` and `textField1`

```
textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      textField1.requestFocusInWindow();    
    }
}); 

textField1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      textField.requestFocusInWindow(); 
   }
});
```

Now when you hit `Enter` when focused on the first `JTextField`, the other one will be focused, and vice versa.

Comment: should be wrapped into invokeLater

Comment: @mKorbel I still don't know in which cases I should use `invokeLater`. Should I use it in this case?

Comment: Focus, FocusSubsystem is asynchronous, then invokeLater delayed this event to the end of EDT, invokeLater notified EDT and delaying events in EDT queue

Comment: should be [`requestFocusInWindow()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#requestFocusInWindow(boolean)): *The focus behavior of this method can be implemented uniformly across platforms, and thus developers are strongly encouraged to use this method over requestFocus when possible. Code which relies on requestFocus may exhibit different focus behavior on different platforms*

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [How to Use the Focus Subsystem](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html)

It will explains how to set the transfer keys for the focus sub system

**Simple example**

```
public class TestFocusTransfersal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestFocusTransfersal();
    }

    public TestFocusTransfersal() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JTextField field1 = new JTextField("1", 10);
        private JTextField field2 = new JTextField("2", 10);
        private JTextField field3 = new JTextField("3", 10);
        private JTextField field4 = new JTextField("4", 10);
        private JTextField field5 = new JTextField("5", 10);
        private JTextField field6 = new JTextField("6", 10);
        private JTextField field7 = new JTextField("7", 10);
        private JTextField field8 = new JTextField("8", 10);
        private JTextField field9 = new JTextField("9", 10);
        private final MyOwnFocusTraversalPolicy policy;

        public TestPane() {
            // Set up enter for focus transfer...
            Set forwardKeys = getFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.FORWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS);
            Set newForwardKeys = new HashSet(forwardKeys);
            newForwardKeys.add(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0));
            setFocusTraversalKeys(KeyboardFocusManager.FORWARD_TRAVERSAL_KEYS,
                            newForwardKeys);

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            add("Field #1: ", field1, 0, 0);
            add("Field #2: ", field2, 2, 0);
            add("Field #3: ", field3, 4, 0);
            add("Field #4: ", field4, 6, 0);
            add("Field #5: ", field5, 8, 0);
            add("Field #6: ", field6, 2, 1);
            add("Field #7: ", field7, 4, 1);
            add("Field #8: ", field8, 6, 1);
            add("Field #9: ", field9, 8, 1);

            policy = new MyOwnFocusTraversalPolicy(
                            field1,
                            field6,
                            field7,
                            field8,
                            field9,
                            field2,
                            field3,
                            field4,
                            field5
                            );

//            You can do this to make life easier, but it may have unexpected
//            consequences...
//            setFocusCycleRoot(true);
//            setFocusTraversalPolicy(policy);

        }

        @Override
        public void addNotify() {
            super.addNotify(); 
//        Comment this out if you use focusCycleRoot
            SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this).setFocusTraversalPolicy(policy);
        }

        protected void add(String label, JTextField field, int x, int y) {
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridy = y;
            gbc.gridx = x;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
            add(new JLabel(label), gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            add(field, gbc);
        }
    }

    public static class MyOwnFocusTraversalPolicy
                    extends FocusTraversalPolicy {

        private List<Component> order;

        public MyOwnFocusTraversalPolicy(Component... order) {
            this.order = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(order));
        }

        @Override
        public Component getComponentAfter(Container focusCycleRoot,
                        Component aComponent) {
            int idx = (order.indexOf(aComponent) + 1) % order.size();
            return order.get(idx);
        }

        @Override
        public Component getComponentBefore(Container focusCycleRoot,
                        Component aComponent) {
            int idx = order.indexOf(aComponent) - 1;
            if (idx < 0) {
                idx = order.size() - 1;
            }
            return order.get(idx);
        }

        @Override
        public Component getDefaultComponent(Container focusCycleRoot) {
            return order.get(0);
        }

        @Override
        public Component getLastComponent(Container focusCycleRoot) {
            return order.size() > 0 ? order.get(order.size()) : null;
        }

        @Override
        public Component getFirstComponent(Container focusCycleRoot) {
            return order.get(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can't repeat it often enough: such a naive implementation of FocusTraversalPolicy will _break_ in all but the most trivial contexts (f.i. when having compound components or real containers as children) because it must cope with the component tree below (until the next nested policy).