# JButton getting focused before a JTextField

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, focus

[image]

As you can see, the **passwordField** is positioned before **jButton1** in the navigator, however, when the **usernameField** is focused, and I press the TAB key, the second element being focused is the **jButton1** and not the **passwordField**.

[image]

What really controls the order of focus?

Comment: I really hate using GUI-designer for writing a swing application :(

Comment: The default focus transferral is based more on the visual layout the the order of the components. In this case it would want to go left to right, top to bottom. This is the expected behaviour

Comment: @Eng.Fouad any other suggestions?

Comment: Have a read [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/doc-files/FocusSpec.html) it will tell you all you need to know most importantly about [FocusTraversalPolicy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/doc-files/FocusSpec.html#FocusTraversalPolicy)

Comment: By code, by your hand.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad this has nothing to do with the GUI form editor, hand coding the UI would result in the same behaviour, this is how the default focus transferal works in Swing

Comment: @MadProgrammer I am talking in general, as a best practice :)

Comment: @Eng.Fouad I really love to design an HTML page by hand, I love CSS, but Java...its different, or am I wrong?

Comment: @Eng.Fouad While I always encourage my junior developers to hand code there UIs, I, personally, use form editors all the time

Comment: @AliBassam You just need to get used to it. Swing is awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default focus transferral is based more on the visual layout the the order of the components. In this case it would want to go left to right, top to bottom. This is the expected behaviour – MadProgrammer just now edit

Take a look at [How to use the Focus Subsystem](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html), especially, [Customizing Focus Traversal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#customFocusTraversal)

**Updated**

Take a look at [switching JTextFields by pressing Enter key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14902410/switching-jtextfields-by-pressing-enter-key/14902740#14902740), which demonstrates the use of a custom focus policy

Answer (score 2):

The phrase you need search for is "tab order": there is an answer to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9480363/how-to-set-the-tab-order-in-swing-java).  Briefly, you will need to implement a [FocusTraversalPolicy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FocusTraversalPolicy.html) subclass, and make your container use it by calling [setFocusTraversalPolicy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#setFocusTraversalPolicy%28java.awt.FocusTraversalPolicy%29).

Answer (score -1):

Try to search tab index or tab order to set for the components

Comment: random api invention? There is no such thingy as _set tab order/index_ in swing components